# java google data transfer でデータが転送されない

Tags: java, google-api

すいません。教えてください。
javaでgoogleのdata transfer apiを使ってgoogleドライブのオーナーを変更しようと
以下のようなコードを組みました。
実行後、googleから「データの転送に成功しました」というメールが来たので、
成功したのかと思ったのですが、対象のユーザーのアカウントでログインしてドライブを見ても
データが転送されてないように見えます。
なにか間違っている箇所わかる方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか。

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Directory dir=getDirectoryService();
    User user1=dir.users().get("usertest01@domain.co.jp").execute();
    User user2=dir.users().get("usertest02@domain.co.jp").execute();
    DataTransfer d=getDataTransferService();

    ApplicationsListResponse l=d.applications().list().setMaxResults(100).execute();
    Application apl=null;
    for(Application a : l.getApplications())
    {
        if(a.getName().equals("Drive and Docs"))
        {
            apl=a;
        }
    }

    ApplicationDataTransfer applicationdatatransfer=new ApplicationDataTransfer();
    applicationdatatransfer.setApplicationId(apl.getId());
    com.google.api.services.admin.datatransfer.model.DataTransfer t=new com.google.api.services.admin.datatransfer.model.DataTransfer();
    t.setOldOwnerUserId(user2.getId());
    t.setNewOwnerUserId(user1.getId());
    t.setApplicationDataTransfers(Arrays.asList(applicationdatatransfer));

    com.google.api.services.admin.datatransfer.model.DataTransfer tt=null;
    tt=d.transfers().insert(t).execute();

    System.out.println(tt.getId());
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(tt.getEtag());
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(tt.getOverallTransferStatusCode());
    System.out.println("=======================");
    System.out.println("########################");



    com.google.api.services.admin.datatransfer.model.DataTransfersListResponse response=d.transfers().list().execute();
    for(com.google.api.services.admin.datatransfer.model.DataTransfer ttt : response.getDataTransfers())
    {
        System.out.println(ttt.getId());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(ttt.getEtag());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(ttt.getOverallTransferStatusCode());
        System.out.println("=======================");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

すいません自己解決しました。
ApplicationTransferParamというのを設定してやると上手くいきました。

```
ApplicationTransferParam p=new ApplicationTransferParam();
p.setKey("PRIVACY_LEVEL");
p.setValue(Arrays.asList("PRIVATE","SHARED"));
applicationdatatransfer.setApplicationTransferParams(Arrays.asList(p));
```